# AWS Java SDK: check if an object exists with a specific version in an S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I know there is a `doesObjectExist` method to check if an object exists in a specified bucket, but how do I check if an object *with a specific version* exists in an S3 bucket?

I want to call `doesObjectExist(bucketName, objectName, s3Version)`.

Is there any way I can do this, or do I need to call `listVersions` first and check if the version exists using the `VersionListing`? This approach seems a lot more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one step check in the current API. You could try using something like

```
s3Client.getObjectMetadata(
  new GetObjectMetadataRequest(bucketName, key, versionId)
)
```

But then I don't see any reliable way to know when such object doesn't exist (because there's no a special "object doesn't exist" exception for such case). So after it fails you should check that this object exists with `doesObjectExist`. Or another way round: check that it exists, then query the metadata with version, if it exists but the metadata request fails, this version of the object doesn't exist.